# Asp.net c# getting value from a textbox in a list view with data that is manually bound

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to simply read a textbox in my listview. It's a shopping cart and I need to manually edit the cookie when the "new quantity" is typed in. I'm trying to use what I did for a dropdownbox, but I'm guessing because **I manually bind the data instead of using a datasource** is the difference preventing me access to the value in the textbox.

The weird thing is that it isn't getting null, it just isn't getting any value? I've added other things to the label so I know it's not how I'm calling label. All the results I find online are calling invalid things such as listview1.items[0].subitems[0], which are not members I can call.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Button Handler

```
 protected void editQ_Click(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {

        LinkButton lbSender = (LinkButton)sender;
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)lbSender.FindControl("tb1"); // this is the textbox
        productTableAdapter ad = new productTableAdapter();
        int idIn = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        HttpCookie c = Request.Cookies["cart"];
        Label2.Text = tb.Text.ToString();
        // Label2.Text = tb.Text; doesn't work either.
        if (tb == null)
        {
            Label2.Text = "NULL ERROR";
        }

           ....



    }
```

Listview

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="productNo" 
         >
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <span style="">productNo:
            <asp:Label ID="productNoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("productNo") %>' />
            <br />
            Name:
            <asp:Label ID="productNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("productName") %>' />
            <br />
            Quantity:
            <asp:Label ID="productQuantityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>' />

           <asp:TextBox id = "tb1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           <asp:LinkButton id="editQ" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("productNo") %>' onCommand ="editQ_Click">Change Quantity</asp:LinkButton>

            <br />
            price:
            <asp:Label ID="priceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("price") %>' />

            <br />
            <asp:Image ID = "img" runat="server" height = "150" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("imgURL")%>'></asp:Image>

            <br />
<br /></span>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I ended up giving up, and just making an edit amount page, passing the product ID.

Answer (score 2):

`FindControl` is used to find controls in a container. From your markup, LinkButton is not a container for your textbox. Your textbox is in your ListView

Try this, am not sure though

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox)lbSender.NamingContainer.FindControl("tb1");
```

Comment: That didn't work, but atleast it's something more to look into!